# Are "plus" and "minus" appropriate method names?

Tags: java, methods, naming-standards

Java SE 8 comes with a new mechanism for dates, introducing `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` classes to represent instants of time. To manipulate such instants, a set of methods are given: `LocalDate.plusDays(...)`, `LocalDate.minusDays(...)` and so on.

I've always thought that good practice was naming methods after verbs describing their purpose, as methods are, actually, operations to be executed, something that will *perform* an action. Just to mention, if you consider classes like `StringBuilder`, for instance, methods' names are `append`, `insert`, `delete`...

This is why to me it doesn't sound right naming a method `plusDays` instead of `sumDays`, `minusDays` instead of `subtractDays`. It's just me finding it very annoying? What do you think?

The only reason I can think of is that dates are immutable objects, so by calling `plusDays` you're not adding days to the original object but creating a new one with new properties, but that's very very subtle.

Comment: I think you're looking at this too technically. The actual goal for method names is to make it clear what it does and to make it readable. It just turns out that naming them with verbs *normally* accomplishes these two goals. However, consider a method called `sqrt` which takes the square root. Naming this method `takeSqrt` might seem to make sense according to your rule, but naming it this would not make the method more readable nor would it make it clearer.

Comment: @Brandin That's true, but what about `Math.addExact(...)` and `Math.subtractExact(...)`? They're not *plus* or *minus*. It looks like methods about operations having a *current english* verb counterpart are named after the english word, sqrt has not a word for it. I think that Ben got the point with his answer. But I admit it's almost pointless discussing at this level of detail

Comment: Programming is not "English". For example, `sqrt` is just a word that programmers are expected to recognize and know. The English word is "square root" by the way. But naming things according to what is natural in English is not good. Take the word "illicit", for example, a perfectly fine English word. However, if someone named their method, say `isIllicit` I think I would want to tear out my eyeballs every time I looked at this method call. It just looks awful and there has to be a better way to express the idea.

Comment: Not being English my mother language it's not easy trying to explain my ideas when things are a bit... twisted. What I meant is that, looking at `Math` class, I can see that developers decided to use the name of the implement function (*sqrt*, *abs*, *log*...) when they had no other way to express it. In other cases, where english language has given them an alternative, they used terms like *subtract* instead of *minus*, *add* instead of *plus* and so on

Comment: `sum` sounds wrong in this context. I prefer .net's `AddDays`.

Comment: @LuigiCortese The method names are chosen to match common English word ordering.  `Math.addExact(1, 2)` because you say "add 1 and 2".  `tomorrow.plusDays(2)` because you say "tomorrow plus 2 days".  If `addExact` were a member of `Integer` somehow it would have been `1.plusExact(2)`.

Comment: @Brandin What looks awful to you, might look beautiful to someone else - and make perfect sense to him/her/them. There is a "language" of acronyms at each job I've had - hospital, gubbernment, etc - that is gibberish to one group but perfectly understandable to the next.

Comment: Personally, I would expect `plusDays` to return a new date x number of days into the future, whereas `addDays` I might expect to mutate the original object. That's just me though, I'm not all that familiar with Java.

Comment: Operator overloading anyone? Oh, this is Java \*hides\* :D

Comment: Sum is not an accurate thing to do here. You are starting with a datetime object and adding an integer number of days to it.

Comment: "plus" is not a verb. You can't "plus" days. You can *add* days.

Comment: I think there's a lot to be said for the overly verbose names used in the Apple/NeXT frameworks - something like `dateByAddingDays` is unambiguous.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> The only reason I can think of is that dates are immutable objects, so by calling plusDays you're not adding days to the original object but creating a new one with new properties, but that's very vary subtle.

This is exactly the reason. Imagine you had some kind of api for manipulating ranges of dates for scheduling purposes. It might expose methods letting you make a statement like:

```
var workdaySchedule = initialSchedule.withoutWeekends();
```

This reads very similarly to the English statement: "The workday schedule is the initial schedule without weekends". It doesn't imply *changing* the initial schedule, it implies the work schedule being a different, new thing.

Now instead imagine it was named:

```
var workdaySchedule = initialSchedule.removeWeekends();
```

This is confusing. Is initial schedule being modified? It certainly sounds like it, because it sounds like we're *removing* weekends from it. But then why are we assigning it to a new variable? Although these two naming schemes are very similar, this one is much less clearly evocative of what's happening. This would be more appropriate if `removeWeekends` *did* change the initial schedule, and returned void- in which case `withoutWeekends` would be the confusing option.

---

This is essentially a declarative vs. imperative distinction. Are we *declaring* that the `workdaySchedule` is a particular thing, or are we carrying out a list of imperative *instructions* (like "remove") to make that particular thing? Usually, imperative naming makes more sense when you're mutating values, and declarative makes more sense with immutable values, as the above example demonstrates.

In your case, you have exactly the same thing. If I saw: `tomorrow.plusDays`, I wouldn't imagine that `tomorrow` was being mutated, whereas `tomorrow.addDays`, I'd think it might be. This is *somewhat* subtle- but not necessarily in a bad way. Without having to think about it too hard, this naming naturally sets your thinking along the right lines in terms of whether or not you're mutating. To make this distinction between these imperative and declaritive styles clearer: "add" (and "remove") are *verbs*, whereas "plus" (and "without") are *prepositions*.

Comment: I actually had a problem with `addDays` versus `plusDays` yesterday! In .NET, the `DateTime` class has methods called `addDays`, `addMonths` and `addYears`. I created method to parse out a relative date (1 year, 2 months, 3 days ago) and called the aforementioned methods thinking they were modifying the current `DateTime` object. Every date in the database ended up being June 8, 2015. "That's funny," I thought. That's when I remembered that `addDays` doesn't modify the `DateTime` object, it returns a _new_ one. So +1's all around for this question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt As a .NET user, I have exactly opposite expectations. I guess this only means that "plus" and "add" are exchangeable, not direct mappings to `+` and `+=`

Comment: @Agent_L That's interesting. .NET conventions aside, "add" and "plus" aren't interchangeable in English.

Comment: Also, for dates and times , it is sort of common to speak of D+1, H+12 and so on to reference time relative to a specific origin (also, for space flight T-10, T-9, etc). Commonly, this is read as D-plus-1, H-plus-12, T-minus-10. Maybe US centric, but that is how it appears to me.

Comment: You might find this old StackOverflow question of Jon Skeet interesting: [What's the best name for a non-mutating “add” method on an immutable collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/521893/44522).

Comment: I have my own immutable number class, and in it I have a function which increments a number by one. I decided to call it `incremented` rather than `increment` in order to avoid the same ambiguity described above. In other words, `number.incremented()` returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET the naming is different although the result is exactly same. Instead of:

```
tomorrow = LocalDateTime.plusDays(1);
```

there is:

```
tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

This only means that differences between understanding of "plus" and "add" ended up as matter of personal opinion. Cheer up, you're not alone, at least you can choose the language which appeals to you better : )

Answer (score -1):

This is probably an artifact of Java using `.Method` for all methods, both those that modify the object and those that don't.

Imagine a language which **also** has a `object=>method` syntax, which would give `method` a copy of the object to work on. Now in such a language, `startDate=>plusDays(5)` is clearly unambiguous. It takes the original date, and creates a new date which is 5 days later.

On an unrelated note, `sumDays` doesn't make sense here. `LocalDate` is a time *point*, not a time *duration*. You can sum any number of durations (and the result is another duration), and you can add a time point and a duration (result is another time point), but you cannot sum time points.